# Setting up Property via CustomAction

Tags: .net, wix, windows-installer

I have the following snippet from our wxs file. I need to understand why we need the CustomAction `SetInstallType`?

I assume that the `INSTALLATIONTYPE` property will be set from the Registrykey.Since it is a public property i suppose i could also pass it from the command line while running `msiexec`. 
Will the value i send from commandLine override the value got from the Registry ?

> ```
>  <Property Id="INSTALLATIONTYPE">
>   <RegistrySearch Id='InstallType' Root='HKLM' Key='SOFTWARE\MyProduct\PR\ROOT' 
>      Name='Configuration' Type='raw'/>
>  </Property>
> <CustomAction Id="SetInstallType" 
>  Property="INSTALLATIONTYPE" Value="[INSTALLATIONTYPE.DEFAULT]"/>
>  <InstallExecuteSequence>
>  ......
>     <Custom Action="SetInstallType" After="AppSearch">INSTALLATIONTYPE.DEFAULT
>    </Custom>
>   .....
> </InstallExecuteSequence>
> ```

I tried passing the value of `INSTALLATIONTYPE` from commandline like  `INSTALLATIONTYPE=FULL` but it is being treated as a new property rather than changing the value of the existing property .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [AppSearch Action](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367578(v=vs.85).aspx) will read the registry value and assign it (overwriting in the process) to your property regardless of what value it had.

The trick is to establish a property precedence pattern:

Most to Least Important:

1) Value picked in UI (if surfaced)

2) Value passed at command line ( if provided )

3) Value retrieved from registry ( if present )

4) Default Value

UI Sequence
AppSearch -  read registry to temp variable
Set Property assign temp to final if final null  ( Not PROPERTY )
Set Property default value to final if final null  ( Not Property )

Display in UI ... if user change value,  final property is updated

Execute Sequence
Same flow to support silent installs.

Comment: Does` RegistrySearch`  alone is enough to search the registry value and assign it to the property ?if i have only the ` RegistrySearch`  does the value i provide at command line override it ?

Comment: 'RegistrySearch' is an abstraction and doesn't exist.  It authors rows into the Appearch and Reglocator tables that are then processed by the AppSearch action.  The property you pass at the command line is the initial value and then it's overwritten by AppSearch.   Log the installer  (msiexec /I foo.msi /l*v install.log) and you'll see the section where it shows this occurring.

Comment: Ok . Will I see these in log when i do an administrative install ?

Comment: i tried it and it is treating `INSTALLATIONTYPE' as a new property rather than modifying it . Seems like administrative install just extracts the contents and doesn't do any thing else.

Comment: Admin install has it's own sequence tables.